# Building SQL SELECT Columns by Option Parameters

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, stored-procedures

I've been asked to create a stored procedure that will accept a number of options (eight Boolean values at the moment) to indicate what columns are included.

I could create a separate `SELECT` statement for each case, but 8² (eight square) = 64 separate select statements. Add 1 more parameter and I now have 9² = 81 separate select statements. That adds up quickly.

I am using Microsoft's SQL Server Management Studio (SSMS) because I am not a strong SQL writer and it tells me when I have done something wrong.

If I build a dynamic SQL statement, I lose the code checking ability of SSMS.

**Q:** Is there a way to specify the `SELECT` statement columns using parameter values?

Here is a very crude example that I have tried piecing together using SQL Fiddle:

http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/5ef0f/1

Schema:

```
create table Invoice 
(
    Id int IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL,
    Name varchar(20) NOT NULL,
    Retail decimal(9, 4) NOT NULL,
    Quoted decimal(9, 4) NOT NULL,
    TaxCodeId int NULL
);

create table TaxCode 
(
    Id int IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL,
    Name varchar(20) NOT NULL,
    Rate decimal(9, 4) NOT NULL
);
```

Stored procedure:

```
CREATE PROCEDURE TestProcedure
    (@showPrice bit, @showTaxRate bit) 
AS BEGIN
    SET NOCOUNT ON;

    SELECT 
        Invoice.Name,
        CASE WHEN @showPrice = 1 THEN Invoice.Retail, Invoice.Quoted, 
        END
        CASE WHEN @ShowTaxRate = 1 THEN TaxCode.Rate 
        END
    FROM 
        Invoice
    LEFT JOIN 
        TaxCode on Invoice.TaxCodeId = TaxCode.Id;
END;
```

Comment: Dynamic SQL is one way to go.

Answer (score 3):

You have hit on the two options and the drawbacks of each.

You can either use:

1. Dynamic SQL, or
2. IF logic that decides which SELECT (of 64) to execute.

There are no other ways.

If you are concerned about losing SSMS' code-checking ability, you can employ PRINT statements during development to see what your dynamic query looks like, and copy and paste that query into a new SSMS query to see what suggestions SSMS might have.

Comment: Yes there is third way :)

Comment: What would this mysterious third way be @lad2025?

Answer (score 2):

One way is to use `Dynamic-SQL` (concatenate column list or exclude from column list)

```
DECLARE @showPrice   BIT = 1
       ,@showTaxRate BIT = 0;

DECLARE @sql NVARCHAR(MAX) = 
N'SELECT i.Name,i.Retail,i.Quoted,tc.Rate 
  FROM Invoice i
  LEFT JOIN TaxCode tc
    ON i.TaxCodeId=tc.Id;';

IF @showPrice = 0
  SET @sql = REPLACE(@sql, ',i.Retail,i.Quoted', '');

IF @showTaxRate = 0
  SET @sql = REPLACE(@sql, ',tc.Rate', '');

EXEC dbo.sp_executesql @sql;
```

<kbd>**[`LiveDemo`](https://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query/434000)**</kbd>

---

Second ugly way is to use temp table and `DROP column`:

```
DECLARE @showPrice   BIT = 1
       ,@showTaxRate BIT = 0;

SELECT i.Name,i.Retail,i.Quoted,tc.Rate 
INTO #temp
FROM Invoice i
LEFT JOIN TaxCode tc
  ON i.TaxCodeId=tc.Id;

IF @showPrice = 0
   ALTER TABLE #temp DROP COLUMN Retail, Quoted;   

IF @showTaxRate = 0   
   ALTER TABLE #temp DROP COLUMN Rate;   
   -- if you use it within SP you need to wrap it with `EXEC`
   -- EXEC('ALTER TABLE #temp DROP COLUMN Rate;');  

SELECT * FROM #temp;
```

<kbd>**[`LiveDemo2`](https://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query/434010)**</kbd>

Comment: Damn, such an ugly thing that second option :D But if it works it works, I guess.

Comment: @SeanLange Third way (not most beautiful but possible :))

Comment: 2nd option may be ugly, but that's very useful to me. Would the end result make a slowly executing stored procedure or would it execute as fast as one created with Dynamic SQL?

Comment: @jp2code I show `DROP column` method to prove [x](http://stackoverflow.com/a/35297714/5070879) that there are always other ways. But personally I would not use it in production code (it is hacky). Better use dynamic-SQL way

Comment: LOL. If the intention is to come up with as many ways as possible you could do more. As you said, this would produce the desired results but doesn't make any sense to do it that way. I could come up with some other ineffective ways of this too. :)

Comment: Well you could use IF statements to add to a vertical table that you then PIVOT into the final result, but the PIVOT would have to be dynamic, so that would still involve dynamic sql.

Comment: There might be some fun ways to do this with a single-column concatenated result and/or XML functions.

Comment: I got it all written, but it's so complicated that I had to declare a table variable to insert everything into. But now `execute @sql` fails because my table variable is not in scope with Dynamic SQL.

Comment: I think this link should work: [point_of_sale_report.txt](https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B4nSZZwpkVnsQWQxdGxfZzBfVjA/) on Google Drive.

Comment: @jp2Code Please edit your question and add your code/attachment.

Comment: @lad2025 - I can't. My boss is very paranoid about any code getting online. I'm too slow at database development to create a generic example.